# jQuery - sorting a list of items by class after they're displayed

Tags: jquery, html, css, list, class

I am creating a script which generates a report about patient's symptoms. The list below is the report list, something that is **generated in the end, after a patient answers all of the questions.** I have written some code which adds a class to the list below depending on patient's answer. Possible answers are "not at all", "a little bit", "a lot". **Items are removed from this list if the patient selects the "not at all" option.**

If a patient selects "a little bit" for a question, then a corresponding item in the list below gets a class called "moderate_risk". If he selects "a lot" then an item gets a class called "high_risk".

I want to sort this list **after** classes are applied, and put "high_risk" items first, then the "moderate_risk" items.

**How can I do that with jQuery?**

```
<ul class="summarylist" id="printableArea">
        <li>Difficultly in completing daily activities such as showering, toileting, dressing, and household 
        tasks, preparing meals</li>
        <li>Bothering symptoms such as breathlessness, coughing, pain, not sleeping, poor appetite, 
        constipation, fatigue, depression or anxiety</li>
        <li>More frequent hospitalisations</li>
        <li>Needing more information about their lung disease </li>
        <li>Needing more support for themselves and/or their carer </li>                    

</ul>
```

Comment: you can use the sort function to achieve this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: So, first I have to add each element to an array, then remove all of the content from summarylist, then sort it with that function and finally add content from the array to "summarylist"?

Comment: Select all the elements you want to sort > sort them > append them back to the parent element - appending will move the element around and not clone them so there's no need to remove them first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend doing something like [I've demonstrated for you on jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/quant/FVHck/).
Basically, you can use the `sort` function that comes with JavaScript `Array` objects and provide your own comparison function that iterates through those CSS classes in order, checking to see if one of the items being compared has high priority. (When there's a tie you can call another comparison function to add another sorting criterion). jQuery makes all this convenient for you by making the DOM elements you want available to you in an Array. Once you sort that array you just have to update the DOM to match. See [Trent Richardson's *Sort DOM Elements with jQuery* article](http://trentrichardson.com/2013/12/16/sort-dom-elements-jquery/).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var priorityClassNames = ["high_risk", "moderate_risk", "low_risk"];
    var $list = $("ul#printableArea");

    // Simple comparison function that sorts by text content of the elements
    var sortByContents = function (a, b) {
        var aText = $(a).text();
        var bText = $(b).text();
        if (aText < bText)
            return -1;
        else if (aText > bText)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    };

    // Comparison function that first sorts by priority class
    // then uses sortByContents function to break ties
    var sortByClassThenByContents = function (a, b) {
        var $a = $(a);
        var $b = $(b);
        var comparisonResult = 0;
        $.each(priorityClassNames, function() {
            var className = this;
            if ($a.hasClass(className) || $b.hasClass(className)) {
                // a comes first since it has class but b doesn't
                if ($a.hasClass(className) && !($b.hasClass(className)))
                    comparisonResult = -1; 
                // b comes first since it has class but a doesn't
                else if (!$a.hasClass(className) && ($b.hasClass(className)))
                    comparisonResult = 1; 
                // Both have same class -- sory by next criterion
                else {
                    comparisonResult = sortByContents(a, b);
                }
                return false; // break out of $.each
            }
        });
        console.log(comparisonResult, $a, $b);
        return comparisonResult;
    };

    // Randomly assign high/moderate/low classes for demonstration
    $("button#add-classes").on("click", function () {
        $list.children("li")
        .each(function () {
            var $item = $(this);
            // Remove any old priority classes
            $item.removeClass(priorityClassNames.join(" "));
            // Randomly pick a priority class
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * priorityClassNames.length);
            $item.addClass(priorityClassNames[r]);
        });
    });

    // Sort by high/moderate/low
    $("button#sort").on("click", function () {
        console.log("About to sort");
        $list.children("li")
        // Sort jQuery object with <li> elements
        .sort(sortByClassThenByContents)
        // Take them out of the DOM
        .detach()
        // Put them back (in order)
        .appendTo($list);
    });
});
```

Comment: Glad it was helpful. I noticed after I wrote it that there is a case where the behavior might be different than desired: if no priority class is present the item won't be sorted. If that's not what you want you could modify `sortByClassThenByContents` function slightly so that comparison result is `undefined` by default (not set to 0) then check at the end if it's still `undefined` and if so sort by next criterion. I updated the jsFiddle code to include this but left this answer as it was since it really depends what you want, and hopefully this example is comprehensible enough.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this nowadays, I think it is important to point out that JavaScript (ECMAScript) has evolved substantially in the 3+ years that have passed since I posted this answer. For example, [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is standard now, making `$.each` no longer needed. In general, one could argue that `jQuery` is much less relevant / necessary. Finally, I would like to mention that it is considered good practice to "keep truth out of the DOM", which this solution sadly does not do.

Comment: It would have also been better practice to refactor the `sortByClassThenByContents` function to be composable, i.e. have a function that takes two single-criteria comparison functions as arguments and itself acts as a comparison function. This would allow arbitrary, hierarchical sorting and also facilitate easier testing.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    sortByClass();
});

function sortByClass() {
    var lis = [];
    $('li').each(function(i, li) {
        var $li = $(li);
        lis.push([$li, $li.attr('class')]);
    });

    lis.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a[1] > b[1];
    });

    $('li').remove();
    $.each(lis, function(i, li) {
        $('ul').append(li[0]);
    });
}
</script>

<ul class="summarylist" id="printableArea">
    <li class="moderate_risk">Difficultly in completing daily activities such as showering, toileting, dressing, and household 
    tasks, preparing meals</li>
    <li class="high_risk">Bothering symptoms such as breathlessness, coughing, pain, not sleeping, poor appetite, 
    constipation, fatigue, depression or anxiety</li>
    <li class="moderate_risk">More frequent hospitalisations</li>
    <li class="moderate_risk">Needing more information about their lung disease </li>
    <li class="high_risk">Needing more support for themselves and/or their carer </li>                    
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question, but the second answer worked for me the best.